# Why lodash drop() operation does not support shortcut fusion?

Tags: javascript, lodash

If we chain a `filter()` and `take()` operations we will get the expected  shortcut fusion behavior where the filter predicate is just performed for a number of items necessary to satisfy the number of taken elements. In the following example, to take 3 elements we can check that filter predicate is performed just 5 times (instead of 10, which is the number of elements in `src`):

```
const src = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const res = _(src)
    .filter(nr => {
        console.log('Filtering...')
        return nr % 2 == 0
    })
    .take(3)
    .value()
console.log(res)
```

However, if we interleave a `drop(1)` between `filter()` and `take()`, then it will cause an entire traversal of all elements of `src`.

```
const src = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const res = _(src)
    .filter(nr => {
        console.log('Filtering...')
        return nr % 2 == 0
    })
    .drop(1)
    .take(3)
    .value()
console.log(res)
```

In this case, the message `Filtering…` is printed 10x.

Why `drop()` does not keep the shortcut fusion behavior?

Comment: maybe `.slice(1, 4)` instead of `.drop(1).take(3)`

Comment: @Slai that's not shortcut fusion. If we add a `map(nr  => console.log('Mapping...'); return nr )` between `slice()` and `take()` then the `Filtering` and `Mapping` messages are not interleaved. Instead, it will print first 8x `Filtering` and then 3x `Mapping`. If shortcut fusion was working then we would see `Filtering`, `Mapping`, `Filtering`, `Mapping`, `Filtering`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

As best as I can tell, the `drop` method will create a second level `LazyWrapper` which will have a `__filtered__ = false` value resulting in the chained `take` method creating a new `view` rather than updating the `__takeCount__` which helps limit the number of iterations executed by the `.filter` method.

You could do [Fiddle for Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/5dys642c/1/):

```
const src = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
const res = _(src)
    .filter(nr => {
        console.log('Filtering...')
        return nr % 2 == 0
    })
    .take(4)
    .drop(1)
    .value()
console.log(res)
```

Which will result in fewer iterations of your `filter` but adds complexity.

Edit: Removed the extraneous `.take(3)` call since it wasn't necessary.

Relevant code:

```
// Add `LazyWrapper` methods for `_.drop` and `_.take` variants.
arrayEach(['drop', 'take'], function(methodName, index) {
  LazyWrapper.prototype[methodName] = function(n) {
    n = n === undefined ? 1 : nativeMax(toInteger(n), 0);

    var result = (this.__filtered__ && !index)
      ? new LazyWrapper(this)
      : this.clone();

    if (result.__filtered__) {
      result.__takeCount__ = nativeMin(n, result.__takeCount__);
    } else {
      result.__views__.push({
        'size': nativeMin(n, MAX_ARRAY_LENGTH),
        'type': methodName + (result.__dir__ < 0 ? 'Right' : '')
      });
    }
    return result;
  };

  LazyWrapper.prototype[methodName + 'Right'] = function(n) {
    return this.reverse()[methodName](n).reverse();
  };
});
```